# Raster and vector layer did not overlay with each other even in the same CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am a newbie in the GIS world, I hope this community can help me to improve my skill.
However, their coordinate is different how to change their coordinate to be in the same value?
How can they have different coordinates?

[raster data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuVrp.png)(image for raster data for reference)

[image: vector data]

These are the information about the layers
vector
[image: extent information]

raster
[image: extent information]

Comment: upgrade to Qgis 3 and this is much easier -

Comment: I fear none can answer that question, cause we do not know how your data was produced. When data of the same crs that is supposed to be alligned in the same area does not, then most propbably one of the layers got assigned the wrong crs, so internal coordinates and crs do not match. We could guess whats wrong if you post the metadata of your layers: Layer properties -> Information -> Extend

Comment: @IanTurton I cannot upgrade to Qgis 3 because my mac version 10.11.6 cannot support QGIS 3

Comment: I already updated the information, I hope the information can helps me in finding my mistakes @BerndV.

Comment: The vector layer extents of x in {606,840} and y in {-568,0.837} do not look like lat/lon extents. Do you know where they should be in geographic coordinates?

Comment: yep, as Dave X states, the coordinates of your vector layer are definitely not matching your CRS. EPSG 4326 is only  180 to -180, and 90 to -90 ° E-W or N-S.
So please check the source and come back when your coordinates are within this range.